# Cocos2dx Android and IOS build

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have downloaded latest version of cocos2d-x from this [link](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x).

And worked on Visual Studio Environment and finished.
Now I am going to build it to Android and IOS for extra processes.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be `cocos2d-x/proj.android` and `cocos2d-x/build/your_projectname.xcodeproject` in your project folder.

Open them in Eclipse & Xcode respectively.

Reference:

- [Open Project in iOS](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_run_cpp-tests_on_iOS)
- [Open Project in Android](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_Build_an_Android_Project_with_Eclipse)

Comment: Thanks. Raptor. It was a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Using command line:

```
cocos run -p android & cocos run -p ios~~
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write your code using visual studio and then to create the apk go to your project folder in the cmd and type `cocos compile -p android`. XCode I think is necessary to build the iOS project.